# NameError (uninitialized constant Modules::CronJob::Job):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

**lib/modules/cron_job.rb**

```
module Modules
  module CronJob
    ...
  end
end
```

**app/models/schedule.jb**

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  extend Modules::CronJob
  ...
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

But I am getting this error - `NameError (uninitialized constant Modules::CronJob::Job):`

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Then you can use all classes and modules from this folder.

Comment: @yu-coder you wrote `Modules::CronJob::Job` but in your code example just `Modules::CronJob`

Comment: yes that's what I want to know why Modules::CronJob::Job error, not Modules::CronJob